# How do I write an XSLT script to import data from a spreadsheet into an HTML file?

Tags: xslt

I need to create an XSLT script to import content from a spreadsheet into an HTML file.

My spreadsheet has 3 columns I need to import.

[image]

I'll have the spreadsheet data exported to HTML in this format:

```
<table class="tableizer-table">
            <thead>
                <tr class="tableizer-firstrow">
                    <th>CARD ID</th>
                    <th>PROMPT</th>
                    <th>RESPONSE</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>Acquisition</td>
                    <td>In classical conditioning, the process of taking advantage of reflexive
                        responses to turn a neutral stimulus into a conditioned stimulus.</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

That data needs to be added to this HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" designation="" enumeration="" data-uuid="61dac34c7de54289a58698d5bfc8e776">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8"/>
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" title="default" href="../../assets/css/main.css"/>
      <title>usurpmcatfc0001</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <section property="ktp:document" typeof="ktp:Document" class="ktp-document">
         <section class="ktp-document-meta">
            <section property="ktp:metadata" class="ktp-meta"><span property="atom:content-item-name" class="ktp-meta" data-value="usurpmcatfc0001"></span></section>
            <section property="ktp:tags" class="ktp-meta"><span property="ktp:topic" class="ktp-meta">MCAT</span><span property="ktp:topic" class="ktp-meta">Behavioral Sciences</span><span property="ktp:subsubtopic" class="ktp-meta">Sensation and Perception</span></section>
         </section>
         <section property="ktp:document-section" typeof="ktp:flashcards" class="ktp-document-section" data-title="Absolute Threshold">
            <p>The minimum of stimulus energy needed to activate a sensory system.</p>
         </section>
      </section>
   </body>
</html>
```

The data from column 1 needs to feed into the data-value of this section:

```
<section property="ktp:metadata" class="ktp-meta"><span property="atom:content-item-name" class="ktp-meta" data-value="[COLUMN 1 DATA]"></span></section>
```

The data from column 2 needs to feed into the data-title and the data from column 3 needs to feed in between the `<p></p>` tags of this section:

```
<section property="ktp:document-section" typeof="ktp:flashcards" class="ktp-document-section" data-title="Absolute Threshold">
            <p>The minimum of stimulus energy needed to activate a sensory system.</p>
         </section>
```

Any help generating this script would be most appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: In which format exactly is the spreadsheet or to which format can you export it? Which tool do you use for XSLT? I think oXygen has support for the Microsoft Excel format.

Comment: I would export the spreadsheet data to HTML. I added the HTML of the table export to my original post.

Comment: I use Oxygen for XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

If the exported HTML is parseable as XML you can read it simply with the `doc` function e.g. `<xsl:variable name="excel-table" select="doc('exported-table.xml')//table[@class = 'tableizer-table']"/>` and of course reading in a column is as easy as e.g. `$excel-table/tbody/tr/td[1]`.

So set up templates for the nodes you want to manipulate e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="section[@property = 'ktp:metadata']/span/data-value">
   <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" select="$excel-table/tbody/tr/td[1]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Of course the base processing will be done by the identity transformation e.g. `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` in XSLT 3.

The only complication seems to be that the main document is XHTML in the namespace `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` so you need to set up `xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` but if the table export is in no namespace the variable needs to use `<xsl:variable name="excel-table" xpath-default-namespace="" select="doc('exported-table.xml')//table[@class = 'tableizer-table']"/>` and any selection inside the document needs to do the same e.g. the `<xsl:attribute name="{name()}" xpath-default-namespace="" select="$excel-table/tbody/tr/td[1]"/>`.